# Creating a CodeBuild project using an AWS curated Docker image with PrivilegedMode=TRUE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I confirmed that `aws/codebuild/java:openjdk-8` is one of the curated CodeBuild images with the following command.

```
$ aws codebuild list-curated-environment-images | grep -A 1 openjdk-8
"name": "aws/codebuild/java:openjdk-8", 
"description": "AWS CodeBuild - Java 8"
```

Despite `aws/codebuild/java:openjdk-8` being a curated image, when I try to create a build project using that image and the PrivilegedMode=true parameter, I get a 4XX error that does not make sense: "PrivilegedMode can
only be set for projects with custom or AWS CodeBuild Docker curated images."

```
9    [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.codepipelines.AwsCodePipelinesCi  -
{
    Name: j1pass-bdb-project,
    Source: {Type: CODEPIPELINE,},
    Artifacts: {Type: CODEPIPELINE, Name: null-artifacts,Packaging: NONE},
    Environment: {Type: LINUX_CONTAINER,
    Image: aws/codebuild/java:openjdk-8,
    ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE,
    EnvironmentVariables: [{Name: MODULE,Value: janusgraph-berkeleyje}],
    PrivilegedMode: true},
    ServiceRole: arn:aws:iam::############:role/cbjanus,
    TimeoutInMinutes: 480
}
1454 [main] ERROR org.janusgraph.codepipelines.AwsCodePipelinesCi  -
PrivilegedMode can only be set for projects with custom or AWS CodeBuild Docker
curated images. (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 89ab67a0-4d00-11e7-8da7-bdeb9326cb3c)
com.amazonaws.services.codebuild.model.InvalidInputException: PrivilegedMode can
only be set for projects with custom or AWS CodeBuild Docker curated images.
(Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 89ab67a0-4d00-11e7-8da7-bdeb9326cb3c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS CodeBuild "Docker" curated images are the ones that start with "aws/codebuild/docker". Complete list of CodeBuild's curated images can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref.html.

You can only set this flag, which was recently introduced, for your "custom" image. These are images that you may have in your private Amazon ECR registry or public DockerHub registry. Sample on how to enable the flag here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html.

So, for your sample you are getting this error because although openjdk-8 image that you used was a curated image, it wasn't the "docker" curated image.

Comment: Basically, I would have to publish the AWS images to my own repository in Docker Hub or ECR to use them in privileged mode, as Java 8 is not included in the `aws/codebuild/docker` image.